# How to traverse String[][] in F#

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015

Context: Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community; F#

I've been learning F# for about 1/2 a day. I do have a vague idea of how to do functional programming from a year spent fiddling with [mLite](http://www.t3x.org/mlite/index.html).

The following script traverses a folder tree and pulls in log files. The files have entries delimited by `~` and there may be one or more there.

```
open System
open System.IO

let files = 
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\scratch\\snapshots\\", "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

let readFile (file: string) = 
    //Console.WriteLine(file)
    let text = File.ReadAllText(file) 
    text

let dataLines (line: string) = 
    line.Split('~')

let data = 
    files |> Array.map readFile |> Array.map dataLines
```

So at this point `data` contains a `String[][]` and I'm at a bit of a loss to figure out how to turn it into a `String[]`, the idea being that I want to convert all the logs into one long vector so that I can do some other transformations on it. For example, each log line begins with a datetime so having turned it all into one long list I can then sort on the datetime.

Where to from here?

Comment: [`Array.concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.concat['t]-function-[fsharp])?

Comment: Well that was simple. Oh well, so much for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can use `Array.concat` :

```
files |> Array.map readFile |> Array.map dataLines |> Array.concat
```

Now some refactoring, the composition of two maps is equivalent to the map of the composition of both functions.

```
files |> Array.map (readFile >> dataLines) |> Array.concat
```

Finally `map >> concat` is equivalent to `collect`. So your code becomes:

```
files |> Array.collect (readFile >> dataLines)
```