# Pipe Array.reduce FileInfo[][] to FileInfo[]

Tags: f#

```
exception NoDirectory of string

let dir = DirectoryInfo "c:\\"

let dirExists (dir: DirectoryInfo): bool = dir.Exists


let rec getFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) : FileInfo[] = 
    let subs = 
            match dirExists dir with
                | true -> dir.GetDirectories ""
                | false -> raise (NoDirectory("error"))
    subs
      |> Array.map (fun (dir: DirectoryInfo) -> getFiles dir)
      |> Array.reduce (fun acc elem -> acc.append elem) List.empty
```

So the last line I'm trying reduce `FileInfo[][]` to `FileInfo[]` or more accurately `FileInfo[][]` to `List<FileInfo>`.

I assumed that because pipe only works on unary functions so that would mean function currying the `Array.reduce` but I kind of got stuck there, something like:

```
let unaryReduce (fileInfoArray: FileInfo[]) = Array.reduce (fun acc elem -> acc.append elem) List.empty
```

Am I right? Getting close... far away...

### Edit

So after some modifying I have got this:

```
let dir = DirectoryInfo "c:\\"

let dirExists (dir: DirectoryInfo): bool = dir.Exists

let getFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) : FileInfo[] = dir.GetFiles ""

let rec recursiveGetFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) : FileInfo[] = 
    let subs = 
            match dirExists dir with
                | true -> dir.GetDirectories ""
                | false -> raise (NoDirectory("error"))
    subs
      |> Array.collect (fun (dir: DirectoryInfo) -> recursiveGetFiles dir)
      |> Array.concat<FileInfo[]> getFiles <| dir
```

I only started looking at F# yesterday, I want to try out using pipes. The error I get is on the last line:

> This expression was expected to have type
>
> FileInfo [] -> 'a -> FileInfo []
>   but here has type
>
> FileInfo [] []

This says to me that `collect` isn't being used properly to flatten the arrays...

Comment: [`Array.concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.concat%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)

Comment: What has that got to do with anything, I want to reduce a 2 dimensional into a single dimension array. Exactly what SelectMany does in C#

Comment: And what do you think the function I linked to does?

Comment: It concatenates two arrays.... that isn't what I'm asking I want to flatten a multidimensional array into a single dimensional array ....

Comment: `Array.map` followed by `Array.concat` can be replaced by `Array.collect`

Comment: Also how can `FileInfo` be returned there is no call to `Directory.GetFiles` anywhere ? And that function could be simpler to write with a list comprehension (`yield` each file and `yield!` the recursive call)

Comment: @CallumLinington ``Array.concat`` concatenates many arrays, not just two, then it's effectively flattening an array of arrays. So that's exactly the function you're looking for. See this very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626512/how-to-traverse-string-in-f/37626615#37626615 the solution applies to your problem.

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yeah i'm using `collect` now, the GetFiles is in the next pipe line (that i didnt get to) `|> Array.concat dir.GetFiles`

Comment: @Sehnsucht I updated my answer trying to use collect, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use pipelining, something like this ought to work:

```
exception NoDirectory of string

// DirectoryInfo -> bool
let dirExists (dir: DirectoryInfo) = dir.Exists

// DirectoryInfo -> FileInfo []
let getFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) = dir.GetFiles "."

// DirectoryInfo -> FileInfo []
let rec recursiveGetFiles dir = 
    match dirExists dir with
    | true -> dir.GetDirectories "."
    | false -> raise (NoDirectory "error")
    |> Array.collect recursiveGetFiles
    |> Array.append (getFiles dir)
```

I wouldn't recommend throwing exceptions like shown here, but I kept that part in order to keep it as close to the OP as possible. Once you're comfortable with the basics of F# and functional programming, however, you should learn about functional error handling using the Either monad. A good place to start is here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop

Comment: Yep nailed it, yeah the monad monoid stuff looks complex so I'm going to look into that, fortunately go pluralsight for this

Comment: I watched that video on it a while ago, was a really really good video, just haven't been able to apply it yet, so got a good base to start :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error you got from your edit comes from the precedence of back piping (<|) `a |> f <| b` is seen as `(a |> f) <| b` when what you want is `a |> (f <| b)` which is just `a |> (f b)` *(as seen in [Mark Seemann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932313/4925216))*

That said you could write something (IMO) more readable that way :

```
let getAllFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) =
  let rec aux dir = [
    for file in getFiles dir -> file
    for subDir in getDirs dir do yield! aux subDir
  ]

  if dirExists dir
  then aux dir
  else raise <| NoDirectory "error"
```

That way we separate the recursive part from the check part.
The recursive part is a lot simpler, more readable and returns a `list` instead of an array as wanted initially (I added a `getDirs`)
The check part is done with an `if` because a match for `true/false` doesn't add value here
and done only for the initial argument as there are little chance `getDirs` return non-existing directories*

*even though it's possible if someone delete one just at the wrong time, in that case you can rewrite it

```
let rec getAllFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) = [
  if dirExists dir then
    for file in getFiles dir -> file
    for subDir in getDirs dir do yield! getAllFiles subDir
]
```

And that way you don't even need to raise an error you just get an empty list for a non-existing directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `EnumarateDirectories` if you need a seq, although with IO I would be careful using lazy collections. This returns all the 56 files I have in my project (sub)directories:

```
open System.IO
let dir = DirectoryInfo __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
dir.GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories) |> Array.collect (fun x -> x.GetFileSystemInfos())
```

If you replace `Array.collect`, with `Array.map` the top level collection will be that of the directories (exactly 5 as that's what I have).

Comment: Appreciate the answer, Just would like to look to fix my solution, only because I'm trying to learn and try out various features of F# like `rec` `raise` piping etc..